# Set form value for hidden page name

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I'm trying to set a html "form value" when a new document is selected in the tinyMCE editor

On my editors static HTML page template I have the value of:

```
<input type="hidden" id="PageName" name="PageName" value="index">
```

When a new new document is selected in need the "PageName" value to set as "NewWebpage"

IE: `<input type="hidden" id="PageName" name="PageName" value="NewWebpage">`

here is what I have but does not work

```
mceNewDocument: function() {
    editor.setContent('');

    document.getElementById('PageName').value=NewWebpage;  //<- New call

},
```

Comment: Are you using PHP or soemthign?

Comment: Perl but in need this changed after the page has been loaded

Comment: "new document is selected"..what does it mean? Is it kinda any radio button click event?

Comment: In tinyMCE there is a drop down that allows you to select new document and is sets a textarea to blank but does not reload the page. Demo at http://www.tinymce.com/ select: file->new document

Comment: tinyMCE creates a new DOM document. In your JS code, `document` refers to your containing web page, and not the page that tinyMCE has created. tinyMCE should have documentation to tell you how to refer to the document that it created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I fixed it with this:

```
document.getElementById('PageName').value="NewWebpage";
```

Just added "" marks and it worked.